# gitlab first login did not redirected to a password reset screen for root

Tags: gitlab

I installed Gitlab 12.7.6 on CentOS7.
I followed the instruction in  [here](https://about.gitlab.com/install/#centos-7).
I had few problems in the installation and

```
gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```

failed, to solve it I changed the file /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb, as describe in  [here](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/letsencrypt-certificates-fail-in-domain-validation/18112/6):

```
nginx['custom_gitlab_server_config'] = "location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {\n root /var/opt/gitlab/nginx/www/; 
letsencrypt['enable'] = false\n}\n"
```

When I first went to the login screen I got a regular login screen and when I tried to add root it said the "Username is already taken." 
How can I set a root account in my gitlab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been on this situation with the exact same infra setup, I think it's a bug that does not give you root reset password on first login (I had no issue with `reconfigure` step, though). If you re-install, it is probably going to get fixed. But, if you want a clean and robust way of resetting the password, following the documentation [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/security/reset_root_password.html), the root password can be reset through the database or framework. In simple steps, you need to run a ruby-on-rails console and then issue a query for your root password (which is, your number 1 in `user_id`) list:
`user = User.where(id: 1).first`. Then update the password (with the confirmation step as well) and Finally save. I haven't put all of the instructions here for the sake of avoiding redundancy.